# Device is not ready error (CreateFromDirectory)

Tags: .net, powershell, remoting

so I am writing a script for my office to put visual studio builds on their staging machine to automate it. I am getting a very generic error though (Device is not ready) when I try to zip up a file after remoting in via powershell. Here is the code I've got for this:

```
$userName = Read-Host 'What is your username for sampleServer?'
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName sampleServer -Credential $userName


$src_folder_Staging = "D:\www\test"
$archiveName = "$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)$ext"
$destfile_staging = "D:\www\Archive\Project\sampleServer_" + "$archiveName" + ".zip"
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($src_folder_Staging,$destfile_staging,$compressionLevel, $includebasedir )
```

at this point, it will remote in but it throws the error on createFromDirectory with 
Device is not ready.

I have the assemblies loaded as I've zipped a file earlier in the script. I have verified the paths are correct and have tested the time stamp code and verifies it produces a usable path.

This works OK when not remoted, so I'm sure it has something to do with that. I am new to powershell remoting so I don't know my boundaries to well of what I can and can't do. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because remote session tries to access the directory using the machine credentials instead of the credentials used to invoke the remote session. Try enabling [CredSSP](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-quot-second-hop-quot-functionality-with-credssp.aspx).

To enable CredSSP, run those commands from elevated prompt:

- On your PC: `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer
  "TargetServer.FQ.DN"`

  `DelegateComputer` parameter is used to specify the server or servers that receive the delegated credentials from the client. The `DelegateComputer` accepts wildcards (`*.FQ.DN`). You can also specify `*` to specify all computers in the network.
- On target server: `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server`

Now, you should be able to run `Enter-PSSession` with CredSSP as the authentication method and pass the credentials:

```powershell
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName sampleServer -Authentication Credssp -Credential $userName
```

Comment: so as it would seem, there is a group policy at my company not allowing users to Credssp onto the servers. until I resolve this with them, I can't actually see if this was the problem. However I did learn something today so I'll give your post +1 for that.